# What is invariance of an equation?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, covariance, time-reversal-symmetry

I'm confused.

Suppose we have a Schrodinger equation with a time-independent Hamiltonian:

\begin{align}
i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(x, t) = H\psi(x, t).
\tag{1}
\end{align}

Under time reversal transformation $t \to t' \equiv -t$ and complex conjugation, the equation gets another solution $\psi'(x, t) = \psi^*(x, -t)$; the $\psi'$ satisfies

$$
i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi'(x, t) = H\psi'(x, t).
\tag{2}
\label{eq2}
$$

What I'm confused is that, in general, if we have an equation

$$
A(x) = B(x)
\tag{3}
$$

which is invariant under a transformation $x \to x' = x'(x)$, then another equation

$$
A'(x') = B'(x')
\tag{3'}
$$

also holds. So the Schrodinger equation should become

$$
i\frac{\partial}{\partial t'}\psi'(x, t') = H\psi'(x, t')
\tag{4}
\label{eq4}
$$

under the transformation if it is invariant; Eq.$\eqref{eq2}$ should be represented by $t'$, not $t$.

After all, I have a  general question: what is invariance of an equation? Or do I misunderstand something?

Also, one should be able to show the time reversal invariance of the Schrodinger equation with starting from the L.H.S of Eq.$\eqref{eq4}$, but I can't...

Comment: If $A(x)=B(x)$ holds and is invariant under $x \to x'$, then $A(x')=B(x')$.

Comment: Oh you're right. What I wanted to say is "under a transformation which includes changes of the forms of $A(x)$ and $B(x)$, such as complex conjugation, etc".

Comment: And you see that it's no new equation.

Comment: Can we say that Eq.(2) is a new equation?

Comment: Yes it is, in the sense that you might take out solutions from there which might look different from the normal solutions. But those solutions are nothing new, and so this equation actually gives you nothing new. (You get wave functions that are complex conjugated and time reversed than the original wave functions).

Comment: So mathematically, it is nothing new.

Comment: So when we use the word "invariance" (or covariance?), it means that "the equation gives nothing new under the transformation" ?

Comment: Yes, but it shows that it is "very much possible for such solutions to exist". As for your example, the Schroedinger's wave equation does not differentiate between forward time and reverse time as both solutions are valid (being physical is a different question). As for another example, Lorentz transformations keep our physical laws invariant in inertial frames of reference.

Comment: Covariance is an entirely different concept. Do not confuse it with invariance.

Comment: Now I understand the meaning of invariance. Thank you a lot for answering.

Comment: Let me then right it as an answer, which you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarise from the comments, invariance of an equation means that after applying a particular transformation, the equation remains the same. Same in the meaning that the solutions of both the equations (original and transformed) are both valid (and in general the same transformation exists between them).

Like let's take OP's example of time reversibility in the Schroedinger's wave equation. Since the transformation $t \to -t$ gives us valid solutions, we see that the Schroedinger's wave equation does not differentiate between forward and reverse time. Another example is the Lorentz transformation that keeps our physical laws same in all inertial reference frames.

The difference between *invariance* and *covariance* can be looked up quite easily on wikipedia here -> https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_covariance . It's a specific case of invariance.

Cheers!!